# Command prompt "runas user:<admin-user> <command>" not executing properly

Tags: c++, windows, command-prompt, netsh, runas

I would like to be able to call netsh from my C++ program.  I have been trying to use system() to accomplish this.  I am not aware of any options for system() that would give the resulting command prompt admin privileges, so I have been attempting to use the runas command.  I have been testing the command in a basic command prompt:

```
runas /user:<admin-user> "netsh int ip set address \"Local Area Connection\" static <IP address>"
```

While the netsh command itself works perfectly in a command prompt that has been run as administrator, the runas version of the command does not seem to work from a normal command prompt.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of windows administrative scripts ! When using `runas` you only ask windows to change user, but you cannot ask for elevated privileges.

The only way I've ever found for that is to use a shortlink. Under the file explorer, you create a shortlink to a `.bat` or better `.cmd` file. Then you go to the properties of the shortlink, tab `shortlink`, there should be an `Advanced` button where you can check `Run as administrator`.

Then you can start all that from a command prompt or even from another batch file with :

```
link_name.lnk
```

Beware, real name may not be what I wrote above : I only have a french system on which the keywords are `Propriétés`, `Raccourci`, `Avancé ...` and `Exécuter en tant qu'administrateur`.